# adjustment for cluster RCTs in meta analysis

Tags: meta-analysis

Can anyone tell me how to account for clustering while conducting a meta-analysis? I read the Cochrane handbook but it still seems unclear to me. I included several cluster RCTs in my MA, I followed the instructions to calculate the effective sample size and planned to use ICC=0.1. So what next? The attached pic is a review that used ICC=0.1 for clustering correction and I am not sure why the Ns in both intervention and control groups are 0? Thank you very much! [image: pic]